Koa send response immediately and then continue executing code after the response
I'm building a backend that has to handle a lot of incoming webhooks, and these are very demanding on response times.
My backend is in Koa and I would simply like to send a 200 response immediately, to then continue the code execution and perform the longer tasks such as processing (calculations, accessing the db etc).
I've tried several ways, but by both calling next() and await next() the response is sent only when all the middleware have executed their part of code.
NOTE: I have already read these answers on SO
Respond to Koa request immediately, continue middleware chain
Running code AFTER the response has been sent by Koa
Delay koa request 30 minutes but send 200 header immediately
My basic code looks like this:
const webhookHandler = async (ctx: Context, next: Next): Promise<void> => {
  console.log('Handling webhook event');

  // 1 check request
  const event = ctx.request.body;
  if (!event || !event.type) {
    ctx.status = 400;
    ctx.body = { received: false };
    return;
  }

  // 2 send response immediately
  ctx.status = 200;
  ctx.body = { received: true };
  next();

  // 3 handle event
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'a':
      // long running task here
      break;

    default:
      console.log(`Unhandled event type: ${event.type}`);
      break;
  }
};


Maybe break your step 3 into its own async function. However, due to how async works in most javascript engines, this may not make a difference. You'd need to somehow run the long-running code in another thread or process.

Koa will not send the request until your middleware function ends. Assuming your task can be handled asynchronously, the task probably needs to be wrapped in an async function that you don't await.
If your task is fully CPU bound then you gotta rethink running the task in the process altogether

ok thanks, I thought there was a way to send the response and continue executing the code, but in the end I did as suggested and created a special handler that I call inside the KOA middleware without await.

I would suggest you write your code like this:
const webhookHandler = async (ctx: Context, next: Next): Promise<void> => {
  console.log('Handling webhook event');

  // 1 check request
  // same as your code

  // 2 send response immediately
  // same as your code

  // 3 handle event
  process.nextTick(() => {
   switch (event.type) {
    case 'a':
      // long running task here
      break;

    default:
      console.log(`Unhandled event type: ${event.type}`);
      break;
    }
  });
};

It can execute your code after returning.
But it's not a good idea, when your long running task requests CPU heavily. you can use muti-process module such as cluster 、work_threads、child_process, or third party module such as  worker-farm etc.
